# Calculation between two or more arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've a trouble with mathematical operations between two or more arrays. I'm storing values in a mysql database from which I'm creating the arrays in this way:

```
$ni = "SELECT * FROM $table_is_y WHERE id = 'N1'";
$ta = "SELECT * FROM $table_bs_y WHERE id = 'T1'";

$net_1 = $mysqli->query($ni);
$tot_1 = $mysqli->query($ta);

$arr_ni = mysqli_fetch_array($net_1);
$arr_ta = mysqli_fetch_array($tot_1);
```

In this way, I should have created two arrays called **$arr_ni** and **$arr_ta**. Considering the arrays in this way:

$arr_ni = (ni1, ni2, ni3);
$arr_ta = (ta1, ta2, ta3);

I need, for example, to calculate a new array with values:

$arr_final = (ni1*ta1, ni2*ta2, ni3*ta3);

Can you help me understanding how can I proceed to do this?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Do both arrays always have the same number of items?

Comment: Yes, they do. Arrays have the same dimensions and the final output will always have the same dimension of the first two.

Comment: You have no ORDER BY clause so presumably you don't much care which ni value goes with which ta value. Also your variables change name midway through. I guess that's a typo?

Comment: It was a typo. Now it's ok. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea in php but i have know about how to calculate so please ignore my silly mistake of variable

This two array($arr_ni, $arr_ta) is contain 3 values.

so you can try like this

you can create $arr_final  variable

```
for($i = 0; $i < $arr_ni.length; $i++) {
    $arr_final[$i] = $arr_ni[$i] * $arr_ta[$i];
}
```

so final get your answer in $arr_final.
I am not sure but i think it's helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented this solution even if it seems a little bit slow. Do you have some trick to improve its speed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think this sort of calculation you better do in the query itself, for example:

```
SELECT 
    table_is_y.net_income*table_bs_y.total_assets AS final_sum
FROM
    net_income
LEFT JOIN
    table_bs_y on table_is_y.id=table_bs_y.id;
```

if you need help on joining/summing your tables before the join, please ask...

Comment: This seems a lot more job for the database, so the website maybe will be more slow doing calculation in this way. Do you agree?

Comment: usually, DB queries are optimized for these kinds of joins etc. . in my opinion,  you shouldn't use php array functions to join arrays together, because: you could do mistakes, and spend to much time on optimizations, instead of letting smart people (SQL) do the work for you. second, sql queries would be easier to check for errors and debugging (easy to run sql in command line or workbench and check).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map`

```
<?php
function timesValues($x, $y)
{
    return $x * $y;
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

$c = array_map("timesValues", $a, $b);
print_r($c);
```

Comment: I've to do various calculations, not just multiplies. For example, a kind of calculus to do is $x[$i]*$y[$i]*2/($x[$i]+$x[$i-1]). Maybe this is not the best solution in this case. Thanks for your support.